# htaccess RewriteRule to redirect from a directory that doesn't exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I am attempting to redirect any URLs that attempt to access a directory that doesn't exist, however I am getting a 404 when trying the following:

```
RewriteRule ^picco/(.*)$ /rangers/$1 [L,R=301]
```

There is no directory called `picco` however, when anyone tries to access a page `picco/index.php` for example I want to redirect to `rangers/index.php`.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the missing URL reported by apache in the error message? (The requested URL *????* was not found on this server).

Comment: In the Apache error log I see the following: `==> error_log <==
[Tue May 22 11:30:10 2012] [error] [client 90.152.x.x] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/test/www.ayrshireminis.com/picco` I assume the problem is because the /picco dir doesn't exist, however it _used_ to so I am keen to handle redirects properly and not just 404.

Comment: The question is: why is apache looking for file/folder picco when your rewrite rule rewrites it to rangers? Did you add `RerwiteEngine On` in your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it - the following works, it seems the introduction of RewriteBase had a substantial effect.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^picco(.*)$ /rangers/$1 [R=301,L]
```